# How to interpret negative log return more than -100%?

Tags: log-returns

I'm doing some analysis on log returns and I notice that returns can exceed 100%. For example, if a security's close price \$1 today and \$10 yesterday, the log return is $ln(1) - ln(10) = -230\%$! Under arithmetic computation, returns for a long position cannot exceed 100% (i.e. the initial investment). So how would i interpret a log return of -230%?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: The change in the log price is not a percentage, it's a value (pure number). To compute the percentage change, you take e^(change in log value). So, a change of -2.3 in the log price would equate to e^-2.3 which is 0.1 or 10%, so the price change would be a decrease of 90% (which, of course, is what a change from 10 to 1 actually is).

Answer (score 4):

Large?                                                  ?

The relationship between normal and log returns is
$$(normal return) = exp(log return)-1$$
Therefore log-returns can be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ while normal ones can only be between $-1$ and $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The result is:

$ e^{(-230%)} - 1 = -89% $

Answer (score 1):

If the value is `$1` today and was `$10` yesterday

```
return = today/yesterday - 1 = 1/10 - 1 = -0.9 = -90%

log return  = ln(1 - 0.9) = -2.302585
```

*check :* [A = P e^rt](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/compound-interest/continuously-compounded-interest.php) = `$10 * e^-2.302585 = $1` (i.e. today's value)

Since investments *can* end up in the red it's interesting to consider a return that exceeds -100%, for instance if today's value is `-$1`

```
return = today/yesterday - 1 = -1/10 - 1 = -1.1 = -110%
```

Now the log return method breaks down since the natural log cannot be taken for a negative number (unless imaginary numbers are used)

```
log return  = ln(1 - 1.1) = -2.30259 + 3.14159 i
```

The curve for ln(x) is only in the positive domain of x.

[image]

[image source](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/logarithmic-functions.html)